# Agricola: Fireplaces and Cooking Hearths

Tags: agricola

Last night I played my first game of Agricola and I was amazed how great game it was.

But one thing  is not clear to me, when owing Fireplace / Cooking Hearth, can I trade for example 2 x vegetable for 4 food (or for example 3 sheep for 6 food) in one Fireplace ? Or is it allowed to trade only one vegetable / animal for food ? And can I trade vegetables and animals at the same time ?

When I played with my friends yesterday we played so that we can convert as many vegetables/animals for food as we can. But when I reread rules I've noticed line saying:

> A player may own several Fireplaces and Cooking Hearths.

So why would I build more Fireplaces / Cooking Hearths if I can convert as many vegetables / animals to food in my turn ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use each as much as you want. The reason to own more than one is mostly if you get a better one later when you could only afford a cheap one earlier; or to deprive other players of them.

Comment: Also they are worth points; sometimes there's nothing better to do, especially if you have a clay surplus.

Answer (score 2):

Note also that you're allowed to trade in the fireplace for the cooking hearth, and not have to pay any resources.

There are two reasons you might want both a fireplace and a cooking hearth, or two fireplaces etc.

**1.** To prevent others from getting them.

**2.** For points. They're worth one point each.

Comment: The Major Improvement Cooking Hearth is worth 1 point.